# How do I refactor this into functional React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Bluetooth app that works but relies on global variables:

```
var device;
var sessionKey = "";
var authenticated = false;

const startBluetooth = () => {
  device = getBTDevice();
  registerBTListener(device, btListener);
  startAuthentication(device);
}

const btListener = (data) => {
  if(authenticated){
    decryptPacket(data, sessionKey);
  } else {
    sessionKey = finishAuthentication(data);
    authenticated = true;
  }
}

export default function App(){
  useEffect(() => {
    startBluetooth();
  }, []);

  return <>
    ...UI...
  </>
}
```

How can I refactor this to be properly functional? There are two problems:

1. How to pass `authenticated` and `sessionKey` to `btListener`
2. How to use `useState` to hold `authenticated` so that I can represent it in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Your majority of the refactor is not about a custom hook, since most of them are doing pure function calls.

When you need to hold the user, you can do a custom one, like this

```
  const useUser = (initialUser) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(initialUser)
    const authenticate = (_user) => {
      // pass user in to authenticate with your api
      setUser(_user)
    }

    return {
      user,
      authenticate
    }
  }
```

The idea above is to expose a current `user` and `authenticate` to any other components.

```
  const App = () => {
    const { user } = useUser(...)
    ...
  }
```

However if you don't want to hold the user, you can make a `useAuthenticate` to only handle the authentication inside the custom hook.

This is the basic idea.

NOTE: a function becomes a hook when it uses `useState` or any other hooks provided by React. A hook is a function, however not all function is a hook.

Comment: I shouldn't have said anything about a hook, I have edited the title. I mainly am trying to understand how to make it functional.

Comment: And how to correctly get the right parameters passed into the callback